# How to check whether two words are anagrams python

Tags: python, string, sorting

I'm dealing with a simple problem:

- checking if two strings are anagrams.

I wrote the simple code that can check whether two strings, such as 
'abcd' and 'dcba', are anagrams, but I have no idea what to do with more complex ones, like "Astronomer" and "Moon starter."

```
line1 = input('Enter the first word: ')
line2 = input('Enter the second word: ')

def deleteSpaces(s):
    s_new = s.replace(" ","")
    return s_new


def anagramSolution2(s1,s2):
    alist1 = list(deleteSpaces(s1))
    alist2 = list(deleteSpaces(s2))

    print(alist1)
    print(alist2)

    alist1.sort()
    alist2.sort()

    pos = 0
    matches = True

    while pos < len(deleteSpaces(s1)) and matches:
        if alist1[pos]==alist2[pos]:
            pos = pos + 1
        else:
            matches = False

    return matches
```

Firstly I thought that the problem lies in working with spaces, but then I understood that my algorithm doesn't work if the strings are not the same size.

I have no idea what to do in that case.

Here I found a beautiful solution, but it doesn't work either:

```
def anagrams(s1,s2):
    return [False, True][sum([ord(x) for x in s1]) == sum([ord(x) for x in s2])]
```

If I run this function and test it on two strings, I'll get such output:

```
Examples:

First Word: apple
Second Word: pleap

output: True

First Word: Moon starter
Second Word: Astronomer

output: False //however it should should be True because this words are anagrams
```

Comment: What do you mean by it doesn't work?

Comment: I mean that it return False, while it should be True

Comment: Please explain clearly with examples.

Comment: Also, your program's problem is with the cases, I guess. But I am not really sure, as there are not enough examples.

Comment: If the two strings are different lengths after removing whitespace &c then *they are not anagrams of each other*.  In particular 'astronomer' is not an anagram of 'moon starter' (trivially: the second has more 't' characters than the first).

Comment: @tfb are you sure about the length? In wiki I didn't find any mentioning about length https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anagram

Comment: @DanielChepenko For two words to be anagrams they have to contains the exact same characters (disregarding spaces), no more and no less. Therefore, if two phrases are of different length, their sets of characters are not identical. And speaking of sets, you can use two simple sets instead of the while-loop and the sorting. Like this: `return set(alist1) == set(alist2)`.

Comment: @MagnusBuvarp You can't use sets for this purpose, since sets do not take the number of occurence of each character into account.

Comment: @miindlek Ah, true, but then he can just do `return len(alist1) == len(alist2) and set(alist1) == set(alist2)` :)

Comment: @MagnusBuvarp No. For example `"aabc"` and `"abcc"` would be true in that case, which is wrong.

Comment: @DanielChepenko Yes, I am sure: an anagram must use each letter exactly once which immediately implies it must be the same length.

Comment: Note that if you do an explicit loop for the comparison, you should `break` as soon as `matches = False` gets set. This way, you won't iterate over the entire sequence if it's clear from the beginning that they don't match.

Comment: @miindlek Ah yes, I apparently didn't think this through.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your algorithm is ok. Your problem is that you don't consider upper and lower case letters. Changing the two lines

```
alist1 = list(deleteSpaces(s1))
alist2 = list(deleteSpaces(s2))
```

to

```
alist1 = list(deleteSpaces(s1).lower())
alist2 = list(deleteSpaces(s2).lower())
```

will solve your issue.
As an alternative you could simply use the following function:

```
def anagrams(s1, s2):
    def sort(s):
        return sorted(s.replace(" ", "").lower())
    return sort(s1) == sort(s2)
```

If you want to have a faster solution with complexity of O(n), you should use a Counter instead of sorting the two words:

```
from collections import Counter

def anagrams(s1, s2):
    def get_counter(s):
        return Counter(s.replace(" ", "").lower())

    return get_counter(s1) == get_counter(s2)
```

Answer (score 3):

As other's have pointed out, your algorithm is given 'false' results as `Moon starter` and `Astronomer` are in fact *not* anagrams.

You can drastically improve your algorithm by simply using the available object methods. They already provide all the functionality.

```
def normalize_str(s):
  return s.replace(" ","").lower()

def anagramSolution2(s1,s2):
  return sorted(normalize_str(s1)) == sorted(normalize_str(s2))
```

`normalize_str` is like your `deleteSpaces`, but it also converts everything to lowercase. This way, `Moon` and `moon` will compare equal. You may want to do stricter or looser normalization in the end, it's just an example.

The call to `sorted` will already provide you with a `list`, you don't have to do an explicit conversion. Also, `list` comparison via `==` will compare the `list`s element wise (what you are doing with the `for` loop), but much more efficiently.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this?

```
$ cat /tmp/tmp1.py
#!/usr/bin/env python

def anagram (first, second):
    return sorted(first.lower()) == sorted(second.lower())

if __name__ == "__main__":
    for first, second in [("abcd  rsh", "abcd x rsh"), ("123 456 789", "918273645  ")]:
        print("is anagram('{0}', '{1}')? {2}".format(first, second, anagram(first, second)))
```

which gives:

```
$ python3 /tmp/tmp1.py
is anagram('abcd  rsh', 'abcd x rsh')? False
is anagram('123 456 789', '918273645  ')? True
```

Answer (score 0):

```
a=input("string1:");
b=input("string2:");

def anagram(a,b):

    arra=split(a)
    arrb=split(b)
    arra.sort()
    arrb.sort()

    if (len(arra)==len(arrb)):

            if(arra==arrb):
                print ("True")
            else:
                ana=0;
                print ("False");

    else:
        print ("False");



def split(x):
    x=x.replace(' ','').lower()
    temp=[]
    for i in x:
        temp.append(i)
    return temp;


anagram(a,b)
```

Answer (score 0):

Lazy way of doing it but super clean:

```
def anagram(a,b):
     return cleanString(a) == cleanString(b)

def cleanString(string):
    return ''.join(sorted(string)).lower().split()
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def anagram(str1,str2):
    l1=list(str1)
    l2=list(str2)
    if sorted(l1) == sorted(l2):
        print("yess")
    else:
        print("noo")
str1='listen'
str2='silent'
anagram(str1,str2)
```

although not the most optimized solution but works fine.

Answer (score 0):

I found this the best way:

```
from collections import Counter

def is_anagram(string1, string2):
    return Counter(string1) == Counter(string2)
```

Answer (score -1):

I tried this and it worked

```
def is_anagram(word1,word2):
        a = len(word1)
        b = len(word2)
        if a == b:
            for l in word1:
                if l in word2:
                    return True
        return False
```